# How can I print out HTML markup based on an object hierarchy?

Tags: javascript

I have a customer list of over 200 on a flat site! I thought perhaps a Javascript object might be good here as it'll enable me to print out the HTML structure dynamically. Is there a way I can quickly build the HTML structure using an object or similar?

```
<ul class="main-list">
  <li class="customer {{SEX}}">
     <a href="{{URL}}">
        <div>{{Name}}</div>
        <img src="/img/{{PATH}}>
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>

Users: {
    1: {
      SEX: "male",
      URL: "https://google.com",
      NAME: "John Smith",
      PATH: "/john.jpg"
    },
    2: {
      SEX: "female",
      URL: "https://url.com",
      NAME: "Emily Smith",
      PATH: "/emily.jpg"
    },
    { 
     .. so on ..
    }
 }
```

How would I be able to loop over the `Users` object in my markup that prints out the above HTML structure into the `main-list` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  const users= {
    1: {
      SEX: "male",
      URL: "https://google.com",
      NAME: "John Smith",
      PATH: "/john.jpg"
    },
    2: {
      SEX: "female",
      URL: "https://url.com",
      NAME: "Emily Smith",
      PATH: "/emily.jpg"
    },
  };

  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const html = Object.values(users).reduce( (acc, {SEX, URL, NAME, PATH}) => {
    return acc + `<div class="customer $SEX}">`
      + `<a href="${URL}">`
      + `<div>${NAME}</div>`
      + `<img src="/img/${PATH}" />`
      + '</a>'
      + '/<div>'
  }, '');

  container.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id='container'>

</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks indeed. What does `reduce` do here in this instance?

Comment: It start with empty string and iterate over each element to add the html generated for this element. Take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeHTML(obj) {
  for(key in obj) {
    const item = obj[key]
    return `
<div class="customer ${item.SEX}">
  <a href="${item.URL}">
    <div>{${item.NAME}</div>
    <img src="/img/${item.PATH}>
  </a>
</div>
    `
  }
}
```

usage:
`makeHTML(Users); // Returns HTML as string`

Answer (score -1):

Like this

I changed to an array

```js
const users = [
     {
      SEX: "male",
      URL: "https://google.com",
      NAME: "John Smith",
      PATH: "/john.jpg"
    },
     {
      SEX: "female",
      URL: "https://url.com",
      NAME: "Emily Smith",
      PATH: "/emily.jpg"
    }
]    

const html = users.map(user => `<div class="customer ${user.SEX}">
    <a href="${user.URL}">
       <div>${user.NAME}</div>
       <img src="/img/${user.PATH}>
    </a>
</div>`)

document.getElementById("main-list").innerHTML += html.join("")
```

```html
<div id="main-list"></dov>
```